# Template / Namespace Interactions

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I came across a compile.. oddity? recently that led me to believe that a template, when created, is created in the same namespaces (or, at least, `using` the same namespaces) as where is was declared. That is;

```
template<class T>
class bar
{
public:
    static int stuff(){return T::stuff();}
};

namespace ONE
{
    struct foo
    {
        static int stuff(){return 1;}
    };
}

namespace TWO
{
    struct foo
    {
        static int stuff(){return 2;}
    };
}


using namespace TWO;

int main() 
{

    return bar<foo>::stuff();
}
```

will return 1 when `using namespace ONE` and 2 when `using namespace TWO`.

Why? And are there other "odd" or "unexpected" interactions between namespaces and templates?

Edit: This was confusing at the time because the same templates were being used across multiple files, each `using` a different namespace.

Comment: This doesn't look at all "odd". `using namespace ONE` would be equivalent to `bar<ONE::foo>::stuff()`, and works as expected.

Comment: I must be missing something? That seems correct to me? bar<foo> is bar<ONE::foo> or bar<TWO:foo> isn't it. So the numbers seems right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not unexpected.  You didn't qualify which `foo` you wanted, so your `using` declaration told the compiler where to find it.

The worst template gotcha I've seen in production code had to do with non-dependent name lookup.  It's pretty complicated, so it's probably best to just point you at the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18) (sections 35.18-20).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what's surprising here. When you say `using namespace ONE` you bring ONE::foo to scope, now recognized as `foo`. In the above code the template gets TWO::foo as its parameter. It has nothing to do with the template, everything that's going on is going on in main() when you call `bar<T>::stuff()`.